# CMake set_target_properties and include_directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

My question is largely related to [this (unanswered) question](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg35497.html) on the CMake mailing list.

Essentially I want to know about the behaviour of include_directories behind the scenes of the Visual Studio 2010 generator; do the directories from previous calls to include_directories get overwritten when you do this:

```
set_target_properties(${Target} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /I${some_directory})
```

The comments on the mailing list say "it shouldn't", but that seems to be the behaviour I am seeing. I understand that the projects in VS2010 are a little more complicated, but I am unable to find a definitive answer. Could it just be a bug with the 2010 generator?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and CMake 2.8.4

Comment: Why do you want to add this line? Why is `include_directories` not good for you?

Comment: @Naszta this line is used to specify other compiler flags too, not just /I. It seems that when I use this with /I, CMake forgets anything previously set with include_directories

Comment: Okay, I understand it. Are you still using it? Why is it a big issue? You could use `include_directories` correctly to define the include paths. Why do you prefer `set_target_properties(${Target} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS /I${some_directory})`?

Comment: @Naszta I am supporting modules not written by myself which use this method. I have worked around the issue by writing some macros to resolve dependency includes and add them as flags instead of mixing the use of COMPILE_FLAGS and include_directories. Your comments were helpful so I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen your CMakeLists.txt, but is the ordering of the include paths good? I think the order of the include paths is not defined if you do it that way. See: [/I compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), [set_target_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:set_target_properties) and [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories) documentation.